# Subsonic Simple Repo for high volume site

Tags: subsonic3, simplerepository

Simple Repo has given me a competitive edge in my consulting. I can finish projects much faster than I could in the "cmd.Parameters.Add(param)" days. As things progress on this end im getting into higher volume sites and wondering if Simple Repo is still the way to go. Im wondering what people's experiences have been putting SR into production vs. NHibernate. Any tips or tricks for using SR in production.

Answer (score 0):

Everything I've read and seen says that SimpleRepository is aimed mostly at the prototyping phase and that most people swap out for ActiveRecord when they move forward.

For me, the transition point comes when I start to worry about how much work it will be to switch over. The ActiveRecord setup for Subsonic still allows really rapid development, especially compared with the "cmd.Parameters.Add(param)" days while still not needing to do a lot of the heavy-duty work that ORM's like NHibernate make you do.

To me, Subsonic's ActiveRecord is a really good tradeoff.